# woocommerce api intergrate in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I have to implement in wordpress api in woocommerce.
I refer this site setby setup bt i am not clear how to implement

```
https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v2.html#version
```

My folder structure is Wordpress/wp-content,wp-admin,wp-includes

In woocommerce/include/api folder i have copied and put them in wordpress/api

```
<?php print_r($woocommerce->customers->get()); ?>
```

how to get in my wordpress site `$woocommerce` variable?

I am very new to wordpress and woocommerce

how to start to implement in wc-api in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please include this in your file.

`global $woocommerce , $product ;`

this is where you start with [woocommerce api](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library](https://github.com/purvik7373/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library)

It's really working for me, I think this is helpfull for you.
Here you can see [Example](https://github.com/purvik7373/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library/blob/master/example/example.php)